# How do I force a Google Doc to save and close, then open again to continue appending? (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to use data from a Google sheet to complete letters in Google Docs.  Know I could just download and use office, but trying to learn Javascript / Google Script and unsure of how to fix the following problem.  Initially, the problem is trying to append to a Doc 189 times, which fails to save, although the console output and writing to doc are all working.  When trying to include SaveandClose, it fails with final being reported as undefined, despite it working previously.  Any help appreciated please!

Current Code:

```
function mailmerge() {
  var countIndex = 0;
  var doctemplateID = "1xMHjKeB-KDx4vz4ch4aPhkkhTgEOGBZpOc7h1KsNqwI";
  var docfinalID = "1g_ZHdI2BLNk5gsxYK5pX5MbHkIpHCfASDDFtB00m1v4";
  var wsID = "1m7HdAuV0bG55oJ6jucQPsWXXb74rLzSheb8o_eSOCJM";

  var doctemplate = DocumentApp.openById(doctemplateID);
  var final = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalID);
  var templateparagraphs = doctemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ss.getRange(2,1,189,11).getValues();
  final.getBody().clear();
  data.forEach(function(r){
    console.log(r);
    
    createMailMerge(r[3], r[2], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], templateparagraphs,final);
    countIndex++;
    if (countIndex%10 == 0) {
          final.saveAndClose();
          //reopen the doc
          var final = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalID);
          }
    
  });
}


function createMailMerge(first, last, opa, opb, opc, opd, templateparagraphs, final){
    
    templateparagraphs.forEach(function(p){
    final.getBody().appendParagraph(
      p.copy()
      .replaceText("{first}",first)
      .replaceText("{last}",last)
      .replaceText("{A}",opa)
      .replaceText("{B}",opb)
      .replaceText("{C}",opc)
      .replaceText("{D}",opd)
      );

  });
  final.getBody().appendPageBreak();

}

Returns --> 9:51:20 AM  Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBody' of undefined(anonymous) @ Code.gs:31

Original Code:
function mailmerge() {
  
  var doctemplateID = "1xMHjKeB-KDx4vz4ch4aPhkkhTgEOGBZpOc7h1KsNqwI";
  var docfinalID = "1g_ZHdI2BLNk5gsxYK5pX5MbHkIpHCfASDDFtB00m1v4";
  var wsID = "1m7HdAuV0bG55oJ6jucQPsWXXb74rLzSheb8o_eSOCJM";

  var doctemplate = DocumentApp.openById(doctemplateID);
  var final = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalID);
  var templateparagraphs = doctemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ss.getRange(2,1,189,11).getValues();
  final.getBody().clear();
  data.forEach(function(r){
    console.log(r);
    
    createMailMerge(r[3], r[2], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], templateparagraphs,final);
    
    
  });
}


function createMailMerge(first, last, opa, opb, opc, opd, templateparagraphs, final){
    
    templateparagraphs.forEach(function(p){
    final.getBody().appendParagraph(
      p.copy()
      .replaceText("{first}",first)
      .replaceText("{last}",last)
      .replaceText("{A}",opa)
      .replaceText("{B}",opb)
      .replaceText("{C}",opc)
      .replaceText("{D}",opd)
      );

  });
  final.getBody().appendPageBreak();

}
```

This returns --> 9:56:38 AM Error
Too many changes applied before saving document. Please save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(), then reopen the document with Document.openById().

Have also tried SaveandClose straight after the function call in the loop, but this returns the same undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but moving the code around has made it work.  It takes ages though as it is saving and closing after each record is accessed - any comments to improve appreciated, or even if you can tell me why it works not but wouldn't before?

Thanks!

```
function mailmerge() {
  var empty = false;
  var doctemplateID = "1xMHjKeB-KDx4vz4ch4aPhkkhTgEOGBZpOc7h1KsNqwI";
  var docfinalID = "1g_ZHdI2BLNk5gsxYK5pX5MbHkIpHCfASDDFtB00m1v4";
  var wsID = "1m7HdAuV0bG55oJ6jucQPsWXXb74rLzSheb8o_eSOCJM";
  var sigID = "1J5JUpqtttW2fdJW_CUCIsSB50QjtpQSa";

  var doctemplate = DocumentApp.openById(doctemplateID);
  //var final = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalID);
  var templateparagraphs = doctemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ss.getRange(2,1,189,11).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function(r){
    console.log(r);
    var final = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalID);
    if (empty == false){;
      final.getBody().clear();
      empty = true

    }
    createMailMerge(r[3], r[2], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], templateparagraphs,final);
    final.saveAndClose();
    

    
  });
}


function createMailMerge(first, last, opa, opb, opc, opd, templateparagraphs, final){
    
    templateparagraphs.forEach(function(p){
    final.getBody().appendParagraph(
      p.copy()
      .replaceText("{first}",first)
      .replaceText("{last}",last)
      .replaceText("{A}",opa)
      .replaceText("{B}",opb)
      .replaceText("{C}",opc)
      .replaceText("{D}",opd)
      );

  });
  final.getBody().appendPageBreak();

}
```